# Result from pandas_datareader not in correct order

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

I have below Python code which works well. Only problem is the result is not in correct order.

```
import pandas_datareader as web
import datetime as dt
import csv

start = dt.datetime(2021,9,1)
end = dt.datetime(2021,9,26)

sembol=['BTC-USD']

btc = web.get_data_yahoo(sembol, start, end)

for ticker in sembol:
    ticker_csv = "{}.csv".format(ticker)
    btc.to_csv(ticker_csv)
```

And this is the result i am receiving in csv. For example; Adj Close price is **49327.72265625** for 1st of September in CSV, however it's value is different on Yahoo historical data page which is **48,847.03**. Any idea why the order of the data seems not correct?

```
Attributes,Adj Close,Close,High,Low,Open,Volume
Symbols,BTC-USD,BTC-USD,BTC-USD,BTC-USD,BTC-USD,BTC-USD
Date,,,,,,
2021-09-01,49327.72265625,49327.72265625,50343.421875,48652.3203125,48807.84765625,39508070319
2021-09-02,50025.375,50025.375,50982.2734375,48386.0859375,49288.25,43206179619
2021-09-03,49944.625,49944.625,50545.58203125,49548.78125,50009.32421875,37471327794
2021-09-04,51753.41015625,51753.41015625,51868.6796875,49538.59765625,49937.859375,30322676319
2021-09-05,52633.53515625,52633.53515625,52700.94140625,51053.6796875,51769.00390625,38884105426
2021-09-06,46811.12890625,46811.12890625,52853.765625,43285.20703125,52660.48046875,65210059683
2021-09-07,46091.390625,46091.390625,47334.0546875,44561.39453125,46827.76171875,49007762488
```

[image]

Comment: Could it be because of time zone difference ?  I saw your location is in Turkey which is ahead of the US.  In the datetime, you could try using the tzinfo option.

Comment: That is also what i was thinking but i just changed end date to 2021-09-20, it is still same.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i found the issue. There seems to be a [bug](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/610) in Yahoo. As suggested on Github;

`df = df[~df.index.duplicated(keep='last')]` solves the problem.